# How to cancel (return from) a Kotlin coroutine from within the scope immediately?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In the following code I want to stop the execution of this scope when an exception was caught.

```
GlobalScope.launch() {
   try {
       someFunctionThatThrows()
   } catch (exception: Exception) {
       // log
       cancel() // this is not stopping the coroutine and moreWork() is still executed
   }
   moreWork()
}
```

`cancel()` does not cancel the coroutine immediately but instead sets the flag `isActive` to false, which requires subsequent checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is special syntax `return@launch`, `return@async` etc. depending on which scope you have launched

```
GlobalScope.launch() {
   try {
       someFunctionThatThrows()
   } catch (exception: Exception) {
       // log
       return@launch 
   }
   moreWork()
}
```

`return@async` can also have an actual return value that is passed into it's `Deferred<T>` val.

`val deferredValue = GlobalScope.async() { return@aysnc "hello world" }`

Comment: That's just a regular `return`, it has nothing to do with coroutines.

Comment: this isn't special or related to coroutines, it's a kotlin thing :)